# Why 'next' is omitted from subscribe call in observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to understand the following line:

```
this.userService.save(this.user).subscribe(result => this.gotoUserList());
```

This appear to work, but what about `next:`? When I try to include it e.g.

```
this.userService.save(this.user).subscribe(next: result => this.gotoUserList());
```

Then I get an error 'name not found'. What's going on here?

Comment: it should be this.userService.save(this.user).subscribe({
next: result => this.gotoUserList()
});

Comment: It is not a valid javascript syntax. It looks like named parameters in other languages which is not valid for javascript.

Comment: @Chellappanவ: Yes, that works now, in the case without 'next:' does it mean 'next:' is optional?

Comment: Eldar: Not sure but I am doing this in typescript.

Comment: It is also not valid for typescript too. Both languages use object destructuring pattern to create a named parameter alike implementation as @Chellappanவ commented above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the syntax you want:

`this.userService.save(this.user).subscribe({ next: () => this.gotoUserList() });`

The using all three observable methods would look like this:

```
this.userService.save(this.user).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.gotoUserList();
      },
      error: () => {
        // do something
      },
      complete: () => {
        // do something
      },
  })
```

I have never seen `next` used in a subscriber in Angular. It's valid syntax, but practically, no code I've ever encountered does this. In the first example, you use the shorthand version, which assumes that you want to do some action on the next observable emission.

The shorthand version is this:

```
.subscribe(() => {
      this.gotoUserList();
    },
    (err) => {},
    (complete) => {}
    );
```